# Module Build Failed - Webpack, React, Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

I was following a video tutorial from plural sight. Course name is "Building a Real-time App with React, Flux, Webpack, and Firebase".

Please see below code and attached screen shot of the issue i am having. Webpack is failing when ever i try to re build the files. Can someone please advise of what that issue could be. I'm currently using all the latest libraries.

[image]
[image]

```
/*webpack.config.js*/

module.exports = {
entry: {
    main: [
        './src/main.js'
    ]
},
output: {
    filename: './public/[name].js'
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel'
        }
    ]
}
}



  /*App.jsx*/
  import React from 'react';

 class App extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        messages: [
            'hi there how are you ?',
            'i am fine, how are you ?'
        ]
    }
}

render() {
    var messageNodes = this.state.messages.map((message)=> {
        return (
            <div>{message}</div>
        );
    });

    return (
        <div>{messageNodes}</div>
    );
 }
 }

 export default App;

/*main.js*/
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, getElementById('container'));

/*index.html*/
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="public/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

/*package.json */

{
"name": "reatapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
 "author": "",
"license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.1.2",
"babel-loader": "^6.0.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.1.2",
"babelify": "^7.2.0",
"react": "^0.14.2",
"react-dom": "^0.14.2",
"webpack": "^1.12.3"
 }
 }
```

Comment: It might be with the `output: { filename: ./public/[name].js}`. Try adding another key for path: `path: './public'`. But I also see that your main is `main.js` meanwhile you have your code in `app.jsx`. Did you `import App from './components/app.jsx';`?

Comment: @LeoCreatini what makes you think that is the issue. The issue started after i added React code. Please see attached screen shot of my file directory

Comment: I also saw a missing semicolon in the `render()`'s `return ();` And a missing semicolon in `this.state = {}`

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see the scrollbar, the `main.js` was hidden from view.

Comment: Just added the semicolon on the return type. Still the same issue.

Comment: @LeoCreatini it looks like it's complaining about ReactDOM.render(<App/>, getElementById('container'));

Comment: Both missing ones? I think it's just not compiling correctly, if so, the error in the App.jsx makes in unavailable in main.js as the log says.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94668/discussion-between-erkan-demir-and-leocreatini).

Comment: The semicolon is still missing in `this.state = {};`, try adding that in `App.jsx`

Comment: I'm try to use new version of package in this course too, but it has a lot problem, since a lot is deprecate function in babel 6 (example alt's decorators)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was solved. The answer was in installing presets `npm i --save  babel-preset-env babel-preset-react`. Then adding another key in the **webpack.config.js**, in the loader: `query: {presets: ['env', 'react'] }`. Should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above steps and followed many blogs and sites for this, but the problem was still there.Then I found out that I was working with webpack 4. So,
after long search I found out the blog:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/part-1-react-app-from-scratch-using-webpack-4-562b1d231e75.
So, I followed the steps and found out that the problem was still there.Then, after long search, I found out that react folder was not present in my node_modules folder.Then I followed the following steps:

1. Delete the package.lock.json file.
2. Run npm install.
3. Check the node_modules folder, you will now see the react folder.
4. Run npm start.
   Then, my problem got rectified.

Answer (score 0):

You can try execute this command: `npm rebuild node-sass`