# query command in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

when I run the following command:

```
query: {presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }
```

I get the following output:

query:: command not found

Which pacakge do I need to install on Ubuntu 18.04 to get the command query? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you want the command to do? Where did you hear that such command exists on Linux?

Comment: I am trying to solve the Module build failed problem. I found this command as an answer to this problem. This command is trying to add another key in the webpack.config.js file. Here is the link to the page where I found the command: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621866/module-build-failed-webpack-react-babel)

Comment: The line `query: {}` is __not a command__ but the JSON object. Your linked answer proposed to add this JSON as key to `webpack.confog.js` file. Please post the question as comment to the answer.